# Win7 fails to boot. System Restore can't help ("Unknown bugcheck"). Please help me

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore

A few days ago my windows 7 wouldn't complete boot. I got a blue screen, which said something like "a vital execution thread suddenly stopped."

Then windows ran System Restore, but it ended by saying it couldn't help!

It said:

"Unknown bugcheck.

bugcheck f4

0x3
0xfffffa8005943b10
0xfffffa8005943df0
0xfffff800033c9d30"

I have trying to read up online ever since, and my head feels like it's going to explode! I thought I could reinstall windows 7 over the old one, but from what I have read, it seems I can't, and I have to start with a fresh harddrive. So I was going to buy a new harddrive, and reinstall. But since this is going to be a humongous amount of work, I wanted to ask you guys, if there is some way I can avoid some of it.

Is there a way I can get my system to work as it is? Or a way of reinstalling over it?

I tried to use a System Restore Point, but it claimed there weren't any! I was sure I had made one some monthys ago.

But the harddrive seems okay. I booted a small Linux which is called Tiny, and I could see all my files, and I tried opening some of them.

I tried running chkdsk /f on my harddrive, but it didn't seem, to help any...

Please help if you can!

Comment: You have to do basic hardware diagnostics in all situations like this, this means a full surface scan of your hard drive with a tool like SeaTools, WDLifeguard, HDDScan, Hirens, UBCD, etc. and testing your RAM with memtest86 or another equivalent tool.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xf4--critical-object-termination